# how to trigger a python script on release cut in github using git actions?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, devops, build-automation

I want to trigger a python script on dynamic runner if any new release cut happens using github actions.

what i am trying is :

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
  RunScript:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:
      - name: Run Python Script
        id: PyScript
        run: |
          pip install semantic_version
          `python3 ./build-scripts/test.py`
```

please suggest a better way if any. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statement so that it triggers on any release cu and it need not to start with "v"

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
jobs:
  RunScript:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: (startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/'))
    steps:
      - name: Run Python Script
        id: PyScript
        run: |
          pip install semantic_version
          `python3 ./build-scripts/test.py`
```